# Angular 8:A platform with a different configuration has been created. Please destroy it first

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

i'm trying to test this simple test service which basically provides the magic number via getMagicNumber api. It's constructor inject a magic Number via Injection Token which is provided at platform level Injector.

But while executing the unit tests against Test Service , i'm getting following error

> Chrome 79.0.3945 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
>     An error was thrown in afterAll
>     Error: A platform with a different configuration has been created. Please destroy it first.
>         at assertPlatform (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31506:1)
>         at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:31489:1
>         at Module../src/main.ts (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/main.ts:11:23)
>         at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:78:1)
>         at Module../src/app/test.service.ts (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:452:66)
>         at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:78:1)
>         at Module../src/app/test.service.spec.ts (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/test.service.spec.ts:1:1)
>         at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:78:1)
>         at webpackContext (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src sync .spec.ts$:9:1)
>   Chrome 79.0.3945 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 ERROR (0.146 secs / 0.127 secs)

Here are the unit test from test.service.spec.ts file

```
    import { TestBed, inject } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { TestService } from "./test.service";
import { MAGIC_NUMBER } from "src/main";

describe("Testing Test Service", () => {
  testService: TestService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureCompiler({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MAGIC_NUMBER,
          useValue: 007
        },
        TestService
      ]
    });

    this.testService = TestBed.get(TestService);
  });
  it("Should create TestService", () => {
    expect(this.testService).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Here is the code of Test Service

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { MAGIC_NUMBER } from "src/main";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class TestService {
  constructor(@Inject(MAGIC_NUMBER) private magicNumber) {}
  getMagicNumber() {
    return this.magicNumber;
  }
}
```

I get above mention error, if i added this line of code in test.service.spec.ts file

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: MAGIC_NUMBER,
          useValue: 007
        },
        TestService
      ]
    });
```

How to fix this issue. Here is the link to the source code.[source-code-link](https://github.com/sameerinfodb/TESTDI/tree/9e43e4a5737092559ce933e005b6b50fdbeb24cb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You import `MAGIC_NUMBER` from `src/main` but in `src/main`, you have the following:

```
platformBrowserDynamic([
  {
    provide: MAGIC_NUMBER,
    useValue: 111
  }
])
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

which configure the platform. Note that when you import a file or a member of it, some side effect can happen. Thus, you are bootstraping your application.
But the test environment already do it for you. That's why you have the error. It's not possible to bootstrap the application twice.
**To solve this, you need to move the token declaration outside of `src/main`**.

For example, you can create `src/app/token.ts`.

```
import {InjectionToken} from "@angular/core";

export const MAGIC_NUMBER = new InjectionToken<{}>("MAGIC_NUMBER");
```

And import it like:

```
import { MAGIC_NUMBER } from "./token";
```

Moreover, you want to create a context that will delegate the instantiation of needed classes to Angular.
Replace `TestBed.configureCompiler` by `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

```
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAGIC_NUMBER,
      useValue: 007
    },
    TestService
  ]
});
```

I have also noticed some errors in your test file, I'm going to make a PR on your github repository.

Comment: I changed it to configureTestingModule , still same error. you can check the github code. i have incorporate the change and i still getting same error. [https://github.com/sameerinfodb/TESTDI/commit/b53b8090a38ca9939fb38301c61a4625e20bbe79]

Comment: @sameer i've just read your code and found the solution, notice also that i'll make a PR on your github repo as i found more error

Comment: thank you will check your solution and will update the comment .

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working fine as expected,sorry for delay response.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I resolved this unit test issue, by removing code from a module.

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
.catch(err => console.error(err));

Because it's already under main.ts file.